# javascript ajax php call returns with 3 more characters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have this php file (stripped down to the essential part)

getBoundaries.php

```
<?php
        $t = "";
        //$t = "t";

        Header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        echo ($t);
 ?>
```

and this javascript ajax call:

```
function anyname(){
    var xhttp;
    var query = "tid=1&pid=1";
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var temp = xhttp.responseText;
            if (temp == ""){
                console.log("ein leerer string");
            }
            else{
                for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                    console.log(temp.charCodeAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "getBoundaries.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(query);
}
```

The output of `console.log` with `$t=""` were 32, 10, 32.

The output of `console.log` with `$t="t"` were 116, 32, 10, 32.

So, my question is: WHY isn't an empty string returned as responseText? Where are these additional 3 characters added? My assumption: the `echo` php-command adds those three chars.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you have some empty spaces after `?>` (closing tag)

Comment: Also, please note that the closing tag is not mandatory. Of course.. it must be used if PHP and HTML code is used on the same page..

Comment: looks more like a space after ?> then a new line with a space in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`charCodeAt()` returns the unicode value of the character:

```
10 -> &#010; -> Line Feed
32 -> &#32;  -> Space
```

So after your echo you get space - line break - space added to your output buffer (probably after a closing `?>` tag)

Comment: Thank you as well for your suggestion. Removing remaining lines / spaces after the closing `?>` tag did the trick.